# Is it possible to get specific static contents of a webpage only using client side technology?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I am only allowed to use client side technologies such as HTML5 Javascript ect.. Is it possible to get specific contents of a webpage using these technologies alone?

Comment: If it's cross-domain and doesn't support CORS, no it's not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is on the same domain or the site supports Cross-Origin Resource Sharing then yes.  You will want to look at javascript XMLHTTPRequest.